# My JavaScript code returns null for getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, null, getelementbyid, console.log

For your information, this is not a duplicate - my question was not solved by similar questions .

I am trying to log this element:

```
<p id="one">Test</p>
```

to the console with JavaScript:

```
var one = document.getElementById("one");
console.log(one);
```

However, this returns `null` for the `console.log(one);` line, and I can't figure out the reason. Where is the `null` value coming from, and how do I make it reference the `<p id="one">Test</p>` element?

**EDIT:** Full HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>A tester</title>

        <script src="index.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="one">One</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Haven't I done that already? That's all my code, and it shows what I have and what the problem is.

Comment: Did you run you script before or after the HTML element is actually loaded?

Comment: Will check now - using `window.onload()`?

Comment: It works fine, I tried

Comment: Can you post your full HTML code?

Comment: When you say that it is not a duplicate, please explain why it is not and show which solution you already tried

Comment: @Arvind what do you mean different frames? I don't really understand that concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are accessing the element before the DOM is ready, Try with [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  console.log(one);
})
```

```html
<p id="one">Test</p>
```

Comment: Perfect! This fixed my problem, thanks so much! Will accept your answer when timeout expires

Comment: @JBDouble05, you are most welcome. Glad that it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2):

It is working fine :)

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
console.log(one);
```

```html
<p id="one">Test</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine.

```
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>A tester</title>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getOne()
            {
                var one = document.getElementById("one");
                console.log(one);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="getOne()">

        <p id="one">One</p>

    </body>

</html>
```